# PHP8 PDFMerger - FATAL ERROR: Count() must be of type Countable|array

Tags: php, pdf

I am using the PHP PDFMerger Library: https://github.com/myokyawhtun/PDFMerger

We regularly use this to download lots of customer documents.
Occasionally I recieve the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($var) must be of type Countable|array, bool given in C:\MyPath\www\PDFMerger\tcpdf\tcpdi_parser.php:503 Stack trace: #0 C:\MyPath\www\PDFMerger\tcpdf\tcpdi_parser.php(373): tcpdi_parser->decodeXrefStream() #1 C:\MyPath\www\\PDFMerger\tcpdf\tcpdi_parser.php(212): tcpdi_parser->getXrefData() #2 C:\MyPath\www\\PDFMerger\tcpdf\tcpdi.php(121): tcpdi_parser->__construct() #3 C:\MyPath\www\\PDFMerger\tcpdf\tcpdi.php(88): TCPDI->_getPdfParser() #4 C:\MyPath\www\\PDFMerger\PDFMerger.php(97): TCPDI->setSourceFile() #5 C:\MyPath\www\\offline downloads\download-DL100.php(75): PDFMerger\PDFMerger->merge() #6 {main} thrown in C:\MyPath\www\\PDFMerger\tcpdf\tcpdi_parser.php on line 503
```

The code with the error line is:

```
    $valid_crs = false;
    $sarr = $xrefcrs[0][1];
    $keys = array_keys($sarr);
        $columns = 1; // Default as per PDF 32000-1:2008.
    $predictor = 1; // Default as per PDF 32000-1:2008.
    foreach ($keys as $k=>$key) {
            $v = $sarr[$key];
            if (($key == '/Type') AND ($v[0] == PDF_TYPE_TOKEN AND ($v[1] == 'XRef'))) {
                    $valid_crs = true;
            } elseif (($key == '/Index') AND ($v[0] == PDF_TYPE_ARRAY AND count($v[1] >= 2))) {
                    // first object number in the subsection
                    $index_first = intval($v[1][0][1]);
                    // number of entries in the subsection
                    $index_entries = intval($v[1][1][1]);
            } elseif (($key == '/Prev') AND ($v[0] == PDF_TYPE_NUMERIC)) {
                    // get previous xref offset
                    $prevxref = intval($v[1]);
            } elseif (($key == '/W') AND ($v[0] == PDF_TYPE_ARRAY)) {
                    // number of bytes (in the decoded stream) of the corresponding field
                    $wb = array();
                    $wb[0] = intval($v[1][0][1]);
                    $wb[1] = intval($v[1][1][1]);
                    $wb[2] = intval($v[1][2][1]);
            } elseif (($key == '/DecodeParms') AND ($v[0] == PDF_TYPE_DICTIONARY)) {
                    $decpar = $v[1];
                    foreach ($decpar as $kdc => $vdc) {
                            if (($kdc == '/Columns') AND ($vdc[0] == PDF_TYPE_NUMERIC)) {
                                    $columns = intval($vdc[1]);
                            } elseif (($kdc == '/Predictor') AND ($vdc[0] == PDF_TYPE_NUMERIC)) {
                                    $predictor = intval($vdc[1]);
                            }
                    }
            } elseif ($filltrailer) {
                    switch($key) {
                            case '/Size':
                            case '/Root':
                            case '/Info':
                            case '/ID':
                                    $xref['trailer'][1][$key] = $v;
                                    break;
                            default:
                                    break;
                    }
            }
    }
```

Line 503 is:

```
            } elseif (($key == '/Index') AND ($v[0] == PDF_TYPE_ARRAY AND count($v[1] >= 2))) {
```

I understand that the Count is trying to count on a non-array value. I have tried using is_countable(); and specifying $v=array(); but with little success.

This only fails with some PDF's. Reading around I can see that PDF merging is not bullet proof and failures do occur. However I would like to understand more about the code in order to ascertain what it is that is causing the error; bad code or a bad PDF (causing an unexpected scenario) or both?

Comment: Maybe you need `AND count($v[1]) >= 2` _But as you dont specify what `$v` looks like I am just guessing_

Comment: you're actually counting a boolean if you do it like `AND COUNT($v[1] >= 2)`, thus the error, use it on the array `$v[1]`. and might be better to check the existence of index 1 just to be sure

Comment: RiggsFolly - Please add this as an answer so that I can accept it. Changing the code to              AND count($v[1]) >= 2)) seems to have done the trick. PDF's are now merging again.
I will post a comment in GitHub as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to count a boolean i.e. the result of `$v[1] >= 2`

I think you probably ment to code

```
AND count($v[1]) >= 2
```